# No free lunch in statistics: an elaboration

Tags: machine-learning, sampling, model-selection

James et al. ["An Introduction to Statistical Learning"](https://faculty.marshall.usc.edu/gareth-james/ISL/ISLR%20Seventh%20Printing.pdf) (2013) p. 29 states:

> There is no free lunch in statistics: no one method dominates all others over all possible data sets. On a particular data set, one specific method may work best, but some other method may work better on a similar but different data set.

The focus on data sets leaves an ambiguity as to whether the no free lunch phenomenon is due to
**(1)** random sampling from any given data generating process (DGP) or population, resulting in samples with different properties/patterns **or**
**(2)** the variety of possible DGPs and populations that are being modelled.
My understanding is that the no free lunch theorem concerns **(2)** rather than **(1)**.

**Quesion:** Would it not be more precise and accurate to replace "data sets" with "data generating processes" in the passage?

Comment: Very interesting question. It's tempting to consider whether a rigorous answer can be formulated in terms of statistical decision theory.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the expression *data set* is used in a more broad sense than a single sample from a distribution. In practice, the expression data set is frequently applied to a collection of samples from the same population, such as a set measurements performed on different days and different subjects, all stitched together into a single object. If this is the case, the underlying statistical distribution is kind of in one-to-one correspondence to the dataset, because in practice nobody really will ever perform exactly the same experiment you did on exactly the same individuals. Under this terminology, the expressions *data set* and *population* are to some extent interchangeable. While this use of language may not be very sound mathematically, it is to some extent justified by the desire to simplify presentation for the target audience

However, under the assumption of the terminology you use, you are correct, IMHO. Clearly, if a method is adequately cross-validated on sufficient samples from a given population, the probability that it would perform differently on a different sample should be quite small.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. A method can certainly perform with varying success on different samples from the same population, especially if the samples are small and/or the method tends to overfit. However, in my understanding this is not what is meant by the *no free lunch* statement. I am also suspicious of equating *data set* and *population*. If that were the case, statistical and ML methods would be redundant besides the function of summarization, as there are no unseen data points to predict and all relationships are fully observable, thus no inference needed; I doubt this is usually so.

Comment: The bigger sense of dataset in my experience is just meaning all the data being analysed, with minimally several observations and likely several variables. I guess this answer is using _sample_ in the scientific rather than the statistical sense.

Comment: @NickCox, your take on my question would also be appreciated.

Comment: I am aware of theorems with this name but I am inclined to interpret this as a variant on the answer depending on the question and the circumstances.

Comment: @RichardHardy I believe it is not meaningful to discuss performance of methods applied to non-representative samples. As you said, the main goal of machine learning is to produce models that generalize well to parts of phase space that have not been trained on, as opposed to competing which model interpolates the training set better. To me, no free lunch is all about the unknown shape of underlying phase space, which can only be inferred from finite data using some heavy assumptions, and different methods choose different assumptions which may be right or wrong for each given situation.

Comment: @AleksejsFomins, that sounds sensible. So do you agree that it would be more precise and accurate to replace "data sets" with "data generating processes" in the passage in cite?

Comment: I agree that replacing "data sets" with "underlying distributions" is formally an improvement. I'm sorry, I'm not familiar with the term data generating process. If I may assume that DGP is "the procedure by which the data is generated", then that is a more broad term than the true distribution. However, for the purposes of estimating ML method performance, two different DGP are equivalent if they produce the same true distribution. Thus, I would assume that in this instance DGP and distribution are completely interchangeable

Comment: @AleksejsFomins, yes, you got the term correctly. I do not think this is a formal improvement alone, as there is a big difference between only considering different samples from the same DGP (or distribution if you like) and different DGPs (distributions). I discovered that many of my students got the distinction wrong when reading the textbook, so I just wanted to double-check to make sure it is their mistake rather than mine :)

Comment: @RichardHardy You are right. Students should learn the difference. Since I am not a teacher, I am hesitant to suggest how to write introductory literature. Perhaps there is some merits to keep it simple and learn the distinction later along the line. But you are surely much more knowledgeable than me in teaching, so if you say that not introducing this distinction from the very beginning is a mistake, I must agree :)

Comment: Thank you for a helpful discussion.